# How to add version info to C++ app in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, versioning, codeblocks

I want to add version info to my app, but I don't know how to do it.

I'd like to be able to make my app look like this in Explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer]

but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create, compile and link with a resource file that contains a `VERSIONINFO` resource. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information about resource files.